# Dragon Dictate 5 on Mojave

Tags: mojave, voice-dictation

This is a bit of a long shot since it's about older, unsupported software. I have two computers, an iMac and a MacBook Pro, and both are running OS X 10.14 (Mojave). I'm trying to use Dragon Dictate Version 5, which has been discontinued (in any Mac version) by Nuance. I installed it and used it successfully some years ago, when the software was current, and when both machines were running previous versions of OS X. I stopped using the software for a while, but I'm returning to it now.

On the iMac, Dragon still works fine. On the MacBook, it recognizes text but will not enter it into any application. For example, I can switch between applications by saying "open Mail" or saying "activate Preview", but within an application I am unable to enter any text.  Things I have tried already:

- I have made sure that I'm in Dictation Mode, not Command Mode.
- I tried using different microphones.
- I tried creating a new profile.
- I made sure that Dragon has permissions in System Preferences - Security & Privacy – Accessibility to control the computer.
- I tried using Spelling Mode.

This wouldn't be urgent if there were a new version of any sort of dictation software for the Mac available for purchase, but as far as I can see, there isn't. The fact that Dragon is still working on my iMac, and partly working on my MacBook, gives me a little bit of hope that I could get it fully working as well on my MacBook.  (I'm aware of the built in speech recognition in OS X, and in fact used it to create most of this post, but it's not quite as flexible as Dragon, e.g. in terms of custom vocabulary or corrections, so it would be great to get that working if I could.)

Any thoughts are welcome – thanks!

Comment: Unless there is a reason you can't, the simplest option would be to downgrade to the last version of the supported macOS on whichever Mac you would prefer it on.

Comment: Good idea @SteveChambers but not an option, unfortunately - for some iOS development I need a newer version of Xcode that is only supported on Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

I utilize Dragon Dictate exclusively on my MacBook pro and holding out to upgrade to Mojave for this reason (using HighSierra). However, regarding a different program to utilize please take a look at Talon. It actually uses features of Dragon to execute its voice commands. It is my understanding that it will work with Mojave.
https://talonvoice.com/

5/21/21 - update, for those following this thread; I did update to Mojave and fortunately Dragon continues to work with my OS.